# simplifying texture and corner coordinates 'openGL

Tags: java, opengl, glu

this is the coordinates part of my dice (a cube covered by a dice texture).
I've seen in some codes it is possible to omit the common coordinates which are pointing to same position ? any way I do it my shape gets disordered!
how can I simplify it ?

here is my code --> the cube corner coordinates , the texture coordinates and the vertex indexes

```
final float pt2[] = new float[] { 
                0, 0, 0,
                0, 1, 0,
                1, 0, 0, 
                1, 1, 0,

                0, 0, 1,
                0, 1, 1, 
                1, 0, 1,
                1, 1, 1,

                1, 1, 1, /* 8 */
                1, 1, 0,
                0, 1, 0, 
                0, 1, 1,

                1, 0, 1, 
                1, 0, 0,
                0, 0, 0,
                0, 0, 1,

                0, 0, 1, /* 16 */
                0, 1, 1,
                1, 1, 1, 
                1, 0, 1,

                1, 0, 0,
                0, 0, 0, 
                0, 1, 0, 
                1, 1, 0 };
        final float texture[] = new float[] { 
                1f, 0.66f, 
                0.66f, 0.66f,
                0f,0.33f, 
                0.33f, 0.33f,

                1f, 0.33f, 
                0.66f, 0.33f,
                0.0f, 0.0f,
                0.33f, 0f,

                0.33f, 0f,
                0.33f, 0.33f,
                0.66f, 0.33f,
                0.66f, 0f,

                0.33f, 0.33f,
                0.33f, 0.66f,
                0.66f, 0.66f,
                0.66f, 0.33f,

                0.66f, 0f,
                0.66f, 0.33f,
                1f, 0.33f, 
                1f, 0f,

                0f, 0.33f,
                0f, 0.66f,
                0.33f, 0.66f,
                0.33f, 0.33f,

        };

        final byte[] vertexIndex = new byte[] { 
                6, 2, 3,7, //1
                5, 1, 0, 4, //2
                8,9,10, 11, //3
                15, 14, 13,12, //4
                20, 21,22, 23, //5
                16, 19, 18, 17 }; //6
```

Comment: Please revise the text; your use of English makes it very difficult to understand what you're saying.

Comment: :) I just want to simplify these coordinates and omit some of them to reduce the length of my buffer (if it is possible)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as a matter of fact what you're trying to do here is definitely the way to go - only specify each vertex once. It not not only saves memory, but avoids subtle visual artifacts where 2 or more vertices (that are supposed to be in the same place) don't have exactly the same floating point values.

Here's an example that I got from a combination of my codebase and [this](http://www.two-kings.de/tutorials/dxgraphics/dxgraphics08.html) DX tutorial.

You are using separate data structures for vertex coordinates and texture coordinates, whereas here they are all jammed together, but the idea is the same.

The important take-away here is that there are only 8 entries in the vertex table - exactly the number of vertices in a cube - nothing extra. You can have multiple references to the same vertex in your index buffer, but that's what you want - to reuse the same vertex entry.

```
struct MyVertex
{
    float x, y, z;
    float t, v;
};

// the cube corners, note that there are only 8 entries
// in table - no duplicates

MyVertex vx[] = 
{
    { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,1.0f },    // one corner of the cube
    { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,0.0f },
    { 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,0.0f },
    { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,1.0f },
    { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,0.0f },
    { 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,1.0f },
    { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,0.0f },
    { 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,1.0f }
};

// index buffer that points back into vx[]

short indexBuffer[] = 
{
    0,1,2, 2,3,0,   // cube face 0 (2 tris here)
    4,5,6, 6,7,4,   // 1
    0,3,5, 5,4,0,   // 2
    3,2,6, 6,5,3,   // 3
    2,1,7, 7,6,2,   // 4
    1,0,4, 4,7,1    // 5
};
```